# Multiple Initial Branches in Azure DevOps Repositories

Tags: azure-devops, branching-and-merging, git-flow, azure-repos, branching-strategy

I was wondering if it is possible to make Azure DevOps to automatically create both `master` and `develop` branches upon creating a new repository. I want both branches protected.

If project level branch policies are set up for both, but only `master` is created by default, when creating `develop` manually via `git push --set-upstream origin develop` I am able to push a number of commits directly on the branch, the protective policies are only applied after.

Comment: Hi @Gabor, is the answer below to create a repo with two branches at the same time by using REST API helps you? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

You could use REST API to automatically create a new repo with two branch created at the same time. Use API to [Create a repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#create-a-repository) first, and get repository Id from the response. Use the $RepoID in next API to [Create new branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#initial-commit-(create-a-new-branch)).

You could create two new branches with the oldObjectId "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000". Here is the PowerShell script that works for me. Need to replace **orgName, PAT, NewRepoName, ProjectID, branch name**.

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0"
$AzureDevOpsPAT = '<PAT>'
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }
$body = "{`"name`": `"<NewRepoName>`", `"project`": {`"id`": `"<ProjectID>`"}}"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
$RepoID = $response.id

$url2 = "https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/_apis/git/repositories/$RepoID/pushes?api-version=5.1"
$body2 = "{`"refUpdates`": [{`"name`": `"refs/heads/<master>`", `"oldObjectId`": `"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`"}], `"commits`": [{`"comment`": `"Initial commit.`", `"changes`": [{`"changeType`": `"add`", `"item`": {`"path`": `"/readme.md`"}, `"newContent`": {`"content`": `"My first file!`", `"contentType`": `"rawtext`"}}]}]}"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Method POST -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body2

$body3 = "{`"refUpdates`": [{`"name`": `"refs/heads/<develop>`", `"oldObjectId`": `"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`"}], `"commits`": [{`"comment`": `"Initial commit.`", `"changes`": [{`"changeType`": `"add`", `"item`": {`"path`": `"/readm.md`"}, `"newContent`": {`"content`": `"My first file!`", `"contentType`": `"rawtext`"}}]}]}"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Method POST -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body3
```